# crontab reboot command doesnt work

Tags: cron, reboot

I tried using crontab to upgrade packages every time I reboot

`@reboot cd /home/toor && (echo "$password" | sudo -S apt-get upgrade)`

but when I check sudo apt update after a few minutes there's still packages to be upgraded
by which I came to the conclusion this command doesn't work

but this `echo "$password" | sudo -S apt-get upgrade` works properly on my terminal,
I can't seem to figure out the error

Comment: put that all in a script... make sure the script works... and then call the script from your crontab with the entire path of the script....

Comment: This looks like you intend to store your password somewhere in plaintext. Please don't do that. You can instead use unattended upgrades or create a custom systemd system service that by default has root privileges and just calls `apt-get upgrade` without sudo.

Comment: Is that your user cron or the root cron? Also realize that cron may run in a limited environment, so specify full path names and set variables explicitly.

Comment: It's the user cron

Comment: Add it to root's crontab instead. Don't do the sudo password thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be late but it might be because the @reboot commands start executing at the start of your lock-screen and by that time your wifi might not be connected so try this

```
((sleep 30) && (echo "root" | sudo -S apt-get upgrade -y)) > /home/{username}/.scripts/upgradelogs
```

put that in a shell script and execute the crontab
this might work